# has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: cors

Hello I have a laravel8 application in backend api at the url https://backend.vente.ci and a react application in the front at the url https://front.shops-ci.com

When I try to connect from react frontend, I get a cors error which is triggered.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.vente.ci/api/v1/auth/login' from origin 'https://front.shops-ci.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't 't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How to solve it.Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: it okay thank you

Answer (score 0):

laravel8 config/cors.php

['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => [' X-Custom-Header', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests', '*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use withCredentials in your front:
for example if you use axios you should set withCredentials  in your app.js file like this:

```
 axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

and in your config/cors.php add your host in allowed_origins section

Comment: this is my axios.js ?

    export const AxiosObject = async (type = "token") => {
    return axios.create(
        {
            baseURL: type === 'token' ? api_url_admin : api_url,
            timeout: 10000,

Comment: set above code (axios.defaults.withCredentials=true) in your app.js then try about it